# CAS ajax request can not get response

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, single-sign-on, cas

I am using CAS for my single sign on, In my cas client I have an main.html page with contains several js files, and some js files will fire ajax call, however when I type http://localhost:8443/casClient/main.html it firstly show me login page, after I login, CAS sever will redirect to main.html, all js files and css files can be loaded succssfully, but ajax webservice call hang there without any response for several mins .

When I restart my CAS client and type webservice url one by one in browser, it can show my the right response, but when I type main.html in browser again, all ajax webservice will hang there again.

Any one can help me what's wrong there?

I attached my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AgentRESTService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AgentRESTService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/agentrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443</param-value>   </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>3</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>html</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>txt</extension>
    <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>main.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

[image]

Comment: works after comment log4jInitialization bean in log4jConfiguration.xml